# The socket connection to management.database.windows.net failed 502 error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Azure SQL Server can be connected.But the Azure SQL REST APIs are throwing the The socket connection to management.database.windows.net failed 502 error consistently.Management Portal firewall rules are configured.

Comment: Make sure you're not behind some kind of proxy: http://askville.amazon.com/Error-HTTP-502-Proxy/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=55109008.